# Have an issue where menu is re-occurring. using switch statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I am having a problem where the program runs itself again after it runs it one time. When it runs every selection is ran correctly with no errors but it never exits the program.  anyone?

---

I feel dumb, I put the while statement so that it does repeat itself.  Ok now if I take of the while statement, what else do I need to take off so that I can run it?

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int in1, in2, in3;
char selection;

do
{
cout << "  Welcome to the CS221 Homework 2 Menu\n";
cout << "  ====================================\n";
cout << "  1.  Multiply two integers\n";
cout << "  2.  Divide two integers\n";
cout << "  3.  Check if a number is within the range 10-20\n";
cout << "  4.  Find the minimum of a list of 3 numbers\n";
cout << "\n";
cout << "  0.  Exit\n";
cout << "  ====================================\n";
cout << "  Enter selection: ";
cin >> selection;
cout << endl;

switch (selection)
{
    case '1':
        cout << "Please enter two integers: ";
        cin >> in1 >> in2;
        cout << in1 << " times " << in2 << " is " << (in1 * in2) << endl;
        break;

    case '2':
        cout << "Please enter two integers: ";
        cin >> in1 >> in2;
        cout << in1 << " divided by " << in2 << " is " << ((double) in1 / in2) << endl;
        break;
    case '3':
        cout << "Please enter an integer: " ;
        cin >> in1;
if ( (in1 >= 10) && (in1 <= 20) )
        {
            cout << in1 << " is within the range 10-20.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << in1 << " is NOT within the range of 10-20.\n";
        }
        break;

    case '4':
        cout << "Please enter three integers: ";
        cin >> in1 >> in2 >> in3;
        cout << "The minimum is ";

        if( (in1 <= in2) && (in2 <= in3) )
        {
            cout << in1;
        }
        else if( (in2 <= in1) && (in2 <=in3) )
        {
            cout << in2;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << in3;
        }
        cout << ".\n";
        break;

    case '0':
        cout << "Goodbye.\n";

    default: cout <<selection << "is not a valid menu item.\n";

        cout << endl;
}

}while (selection != '0' );
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your input? Post some inputs, as it works fine for me : http://ideone.com/Oe1Mi

Comment: Note that you are missing some `break`s there.

Answer (score 2):

Even though it works at [ideone](http://ideone.com/Oe1Mi), I guess if there is any problem, then the problem is with the *type* of `selection`, as using it means reading character by character, including newline and all. So a better choice of *type* for `selection` would be `int`, as it will read only integers, skipping all other characters which might be inviting problems.

I would suggest you to change the type of `selection` from `char` to `int`, and use `0`,`1`, `2` etc, rather than `'0'`,`'1'`, `'2'` etc.

By the way, you forgot to use `break` in `case '0'`:

```
case 0: //<--- I changed it from '0' to 0, assuming selection's type is int
    cout << "Goodbye.\n";
    break; //add this line!
```

Don't forgot to change this (and in all `case` statements):

```
while(selection != 0); //changed '0' to 0
```

Comment: thanks for the break after case 0.  I actually caught that right now when I ran it because it would tell me "0" was invalid when I would choose it as an option

Comment: @Luis: In that case, I smell there is some other problem with your code, as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
case '0':
        cout << "Goodbye.\n";
```

I think you're missing a `return 0;` statement here.

Comment: If the execution comes here and prints `Goodbye`, it will inevitably encounter the condition in `while()` as well, which will eventually break the loop, which implies `return 0` is not needed in the case `'0'`.

Answer (score 0):

Exit works for me, but you still have incorrect minimum checking. (try whit 1 3 2)

I would write that part like.

```
 #include <algorithm>
 .
 .
 .

 int m = min(in1,in2);
 m = min(m,in3);
 cout << m;
```

Comment: the minimum checking actually runs perfect regardless of the numbers I type in.